# Error encountered while training a model - NotFoundError: Graph execution error:

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am following along https://youtu.be/ZLIPkmmDJAc, I encountered this error while trying to start training the model.

GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 12GB
tensorflow v2.10.1

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\TF2\audioclassification.ipynb Cell 57 in ()
----> 1 hist = model.fit(train, epochs=4, validation_data=test)

File c:\Users\Markl\.conda\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback..error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File c:\Users\Markl\.conda\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py:54, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     52 try:
     53   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 54   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     55                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     57   if name is not None:

NotFoundError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sequential/conv2d_1/Relu' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "c:\Users\Markl\.conda\envs\tf2\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
...
  Profiling failure on CUDNN engine 5#TC: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Out of memory while trying to allocate 20119552 bytes.
  Profiling failure on CUDNN engine 5: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Out of memory while trying to allocate 20119552 bytes.
  Profiling failure on CUDNN engine 7#TC: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Out of memory while trying to allocate 1772130304 bytes.
  Profiling failure on CUDNN engine 7: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Out of memory while trying to allocate 1772130304 bytes.
     [[{{node sequential/conv2d_1/Relu}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_13914]
```

Expecting the model to start training.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.